# Differences in Contributions Between Case Study Papers and Full Papers in Human-computer Interaction

Tags: publications, research-process, computer-science, case-study

I am currently trying to understand the nuances of different types of publications within the Human-computer Interaction (HCI) field. Specifically, I am interested in the differences between case study papers and full research papers in terms of their contributions to the field.

What are the key differences in the nature and scale of contributions made by a case study paper compared to a full research paper in HCI?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that HCI is special in this regard? You've mentioned the field, but haven't said anything about why, other than you are interested in it.